# Cloudformation how to import existing resources into Stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

We have a lot of resources created manually. How do I add them to CloudFormation stack without manually adding each of them in template? There are so many resources added manually, that's why it will take too much time If I start adding them manually one by one to template.

Update:
Looks like there is no other way than adding them to new template manually. I completed it by updating the infrastructure with new template for the resources that I wanted to sync on PROD env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to do it manually. But to jump start the process you can use [former2](https://github.com/iann0036/former2) tool, which can generate the cloudformation templates from existing resources for you.